# Mautic Contact Field Api request returning 400 in response

Tags: symfony, custom-fields, mautic

I'm trying to create contact fields in mautic via api and using oauth 2 for authentication. Here is the response I'm getting

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 400,
            "message": "order: This value is not valid.",
            "details": {
                "order": [
                    "This value is not valid."
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "error": {
        "message": "order: This value is not valid. (`error` is deprecated as of 2.6.0 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the `errors` array instead.)",
        "code": 400,
        "details": {
            "order": [
                "This value is not valid."
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I've worked with mautic api before and the order parameter was never required. Also when I tried to pass parameter order as an int value it was not accepting that as well.

Comment: I have the same kind of problem and I can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause of your issue but I had the same response from using /fields/contacts/new and the path actually needs to be /fields/contact/new.

Also, I noticed that you need to flatten out some of the keys for example using the properties attribute you need to submit the key as properties[key] - see below:

```
requests.post(url=self.url + '/fields/contact/new', headers=self.header, 
        data={
              'label': 'somelabel',
              'type': 'mautic data type',
              'properties[key]': 'value'
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mautic 3.1 and have the same issue with the PHP `mautic/api-library`. Unsetting or not passing the `order` property fixes the issue. Although, I'm not sure why it's not accepting the value for `order` because I'm using the same value returned from the API to get the field definition (not changing the value).